# How to wait for biometricPrompt.authentication(promptInfo, cryptoObject) to complete authentication task in a function?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-biometric-prompt

I am writing an Android sign function which takes in a byte[] plaintext & return byte[] signature. It uses the private of the Secure Element from Android phone to sign which requires Biometric authentication (biometricPrompt.authentication).

I have tried many ways to do it but it fails every time. This code below doesn't show the Biometric prompt during run, it just freezes at main screen because of the biometricPrompt.wait(). I have searched a lot for the solution but can't find any. Please help. :)

```
  private MainActivityTest mainAct = null;
  private byte[] sig = null;

  public AndroidSecureElement(MainActivity mainAct){
    this.mainAct = mainAct;
  }

  public byte[] signSE(final String alias, final byte[] plaintext) throws Exception {
    final Executor executor;
    final BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;
    final BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo;

    KeyStore keyStore = null;
    final Signature s;
    PrivateKey privKey = null;

    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    keyStore.load(null);

    privKey = (PrivateKey)keyStore.getKey(alias, null);

    if(privKey.getAlgorithm().equalsIgnoreCase("RSA")){
        s = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    }
    else if(privKey.getAlgorithm().equalsIgnoreCase("EC")){
        s = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
    }
    else{
        throw new Exception("Sign Failed: Unknown Algorithm found: "+privKey.getAlgorithm());
    }

    privKey = (PrivateKey)keyStore.getKey(alias, null);
    s.initSign(privKey);

    executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(mainAct);
    biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(mainAct,
            executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode,
                                          @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
            Toast.makeText(mainAct.getApplicationContext(),
                    "Authentication error: " + errString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            this.notify();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                @NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {

            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
            Toast.makeText(mainAct.getApplicationContext(),
                    "Authentication succeeded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {
                Signature s = result.getCryptoObject().getSignature();
                s.update(plaintext);
                sig = s.sign();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(mainAct.getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sign failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            finally{
                this.notify();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
            super.onAuthenticationFailed();
            Toast.makeText(mainAct.getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            this.notify();
        }
    });

    promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Biometric login for Secure Element access")
            .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
            .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
            .setConfirmationRequired(true)
            .build()
    ;

    biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo, new BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(s));

    synchronized (biometricPrompt) {
        biometricPrompt.wait();
    }

    return sig;
  }
```

Comment: Pretty sure you have to call `.wait()` on a background thread to ensure it doesn't block the UI thread.